# What exactly is GNUPG?

Tags: gnupg

I understand what a public and private key pair are. You can encrypt and decrypt a data stream using the public and private key pair. But I have a few questions.

1. Do the public and private key only work in conjunction with each other?
2. what is a keyring?
3. What is key signing and how does it work?
4. If I encrypt a message with a key, does it implicitly mean I also signed it? After all, only the other key pair can decrpyt it and this key pair is in my possession.
5. And how does GNU PG fit into all of this? From what I read, it seems like GNU PG manages all you public and private key pairs. Is that true?

Sorry, if the questions seem very basic.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The question is unclear, so I think you would be well-served by reading up on public-key cryptography (asymmetric encryption).

   - From the GnuPG faq, [7.1. What’s ‘public-key cryptography’?](http://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#define_asymc)
   - From Wikipedia, [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
   - From Mozilla Developer Network, 
     [Introduction to Public-Key Cryptography](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_Public-Key_Cryptography)
2. You'll be able to answer this after reading some of the above.
3. If you read all of the above, you'd have your answer.  Alternatively, check out [8.12. How do I use another person’s certificate?](http://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#using_certificates)
4. No. You'll understand after reading up a bit on asymmetric encryption, but basically: you encrypt messages with other people's public keys; you sign messages with your own private key.
5. GnuPG is one of (IMHO the best) option for managing PGP keys and performing encryption & signing operations. See [3.1. What’s GnuPG?](http://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#whats_gnupg)